# Magento2 - CSV Export problem

Tags: magento2, csv, export

Using cron job in Magento my database is exported (`.csv`). In my server every `5` minutes but in this way server becomes full quickly. Is it possible to override previous `.csv`  in server and not create a new `.csv` every `5` minutes?

Comment: Post the code you used to export the product csv file which is executing with cron job

Comment: DO YOU MEAN THIS?
 <?xml version="1.0"?><files> 
<file filename="trovaprezzi.csv" search=";" replace=","> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:variable name="sepstart" select="''"/> 
<xsl:variable name="sepend" select="'|'"/> 
<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="objects/object">